Consulta jpa a tabla de relacion n M dado el id de m quiero las lista de n
Tengo persona y representante.
una persona muhcos representantem un representante muchos representado.
un represéntate y un representado no dejan de ser persona por tanto la tabla representante es la intermedia entre persona y persona. la que guarda los id de relación.
tengo esta query
@Override
    public Optional<Person> findByIdWithRepresentations(Long id) {
        String queryString = "SELECT DISTINCT p FROM Person p "
                + "LEFT JOIN FETCH p.setRepresentatives sr "
                + "LEFT JOIN FETCH sr.represented "
                + "LEFT JOIN FETCH p.setRepresentedPersons sp "
                + "LEFT JOIN FETCH sp.representative " + "WHERE p.id = :id";

        try {
            Person person = entityManager.createQuery(queryString, Person.class)
                    .setParameter("id", id).getSingleResult();
            return Optional.of(person);
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }

la entidad persona
public class Person extends CommonPerson {
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "representative")
    private Set<LegalRepresentative> setRepresentatives;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "represented")
    private Set<LegalRepresentative> setRepresentedPersons;
}

la tabla de relacion
public class LegalRepresentative implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private LegalRepresentativeId id;

@ManyToOne
@MapsId("idRepresented")
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_REPRESENTED")
private Person represented;

@ManyToOne
@MapsId("idRepresentative")
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_REPRESENTATIVE")
private Person representative;

@Column(name = "ACTIVE")
private boolean active;

@Column(name = "DATE_DELETE")
private LocalDate dateDelete;

La clase de id compuesto
public class LegalRepresentativeId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "ID_REPRESENTATIVE")
    private long idRepresentative;

    @Column(name = "ID_REPRESENTED")
    private long idRepresented;

el problema es que dado un id de representative el set de represented viene a 0. no consigo cuadrar mediante consulta que funcione. he realziado mil variacioes con chatgpt pero no he sido capaz
